# How to share a OneDrive file using powershell?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, file-permissions, onedrive

I have 3 files inside a subsolder of my OneDrive, say "Documens/TopFolder/SubFolder"

I can list 3 files inside this SubFolder using

```
Get-PnPFolder -FolderRelativeUrl "Documens/TopFolder/SubFolder"
```

> ```
> File1.xlsx
> File2.xlsx
> File3.xlsx
> ```

Now I want to share these 3 files with 3 different users, say

- File1 with User1@abc.com
- File2 with User2@abc.com
- File3 with User3@abc.com

I am a user in my organization, so I don't have admin access to share point. I just started learning powershell.

Questions are:

1. How to get these 3 files into `Get-PnPListItem`?
2. How to give permission for each file using windows powershell?
3. How to get the annonymus weburl link for each file to share with individual user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Set-PnPListItemPermission` to grant user permissions. Example:

```
Set-PnPListItemPermission -List 'Documents' -Identity 1 -User 'user@contoso.com' -AddRole 'Contribute'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/set-pnplistitempermission?view=sharepoint-ps

Below articles may be helpful to you:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/09/sharepoint-online-set-folder-permissions-powershell.html

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/11/sharepoint-online-grant-permission-to-list-item-using-powershell.html

Comment: Thanks Michael Han for looking into it. But, how to know the -Identity # for each file ?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a way to filler the ListItem bases on FileNames and get the Identity Number.
As below

```
#Set Variables
$SiteURL= "https://abc-my.sharepoint.com/personal/Testing/"
#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

$ListName="Documents"
#Get All Files from the document library - In batches of 500 and filter File Names Starting with "File_"
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 500 | Where {$_["FileLeafRef"] -like "File_*"} 
ForEach($Item in $ListItems)
{


    $DocumentsData += New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    FileName = $Item.FieldValues['FileLeafRef']
    FileURL = $Item.FieldValues['FileRef']
    FileID = $Item.FieldValues['ID']
    }

}

$DocumentsData 

Set-PnPListItemPermission -List 'Documents' -Identity 1 -User 'Test1@abc.com' -AddRole 'Contribute'

Send-PnPMail -To Test1@abc.com -Cc Test2@abc.com  -Subject "Your OD File Link" -Body "Here is the WEB URL LINK"
```

Is there any PnpAPI to get the Anonymous URL link for a file on OneDrive, that i can put in the -Body string of the email ?